# Falling Sand simulation

Tags: simulation, physics, cellular-automata

I'm trying to re-create a 'falling sand' simulation, similar to those various web toys that are out there doing the same thing - and I'm failing pretty hard. I'm not really sure where to begin. I'm trying to use cellular automata to model the behavior of the sand particles, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to make the direction in which I update the 'world' not matter...

For example, one of the particle types I'd like to have is Plant. When Plant comes in contact with Water, Plant turns that Water particle into another Plant particle. The problem here though is that if I'm updating the game world from top to bottom and left to right, then a Plant particle placed in the middle of a sea of Water particles will immediately cause all of the Water particles to the right and below that new Plant particle to turn into Plants. This is not the behavior I am expecting. =(

Comment: I've been re-thinking this whole problem, lately... I've been trying to treat the world as a bag of particles that have positions -- but what I should instead be doing is treating the world as a matrix of connected cells.

Answer (score 4):

One straightforward solution is to not do each iteration in-place. Instead, every time you update the world, create a copy of it... then look at the original, but update the copy. That way the order of updating does not matter any more, because you are completely disregarding your updates while you're looking for particles.

Comment: The problem here though is if two particles try to occupy the same space. Say I have two sand particles, each one right next to the other horizontally. During the update, the first particle picks the spot right under it to fall onto. The second particle (randomly) chooses the same exact spot to fall onto - but it won't know that spot is taken, because it is only considering the previous world state, and not the new state currently being created. Both particles end up in the same place, which is the same as one particle being spontaneously destroyed.

Comment: In that case you can look at both the present state (to avoid collisions) and the past state (to see which other update rules to apply).

Comment: I'd like to avoid having all my rules have to reference both states. It just seems like a kludge to me. =\

Comment: So you'd like to consider both the previous and the new state without actually referencing the states that you want to consider? Well, good luck with that. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't program it in a sequential way (looping over all particles) but use real simulation programming techniques in which every particle is treated as an individual object/agent that obeys the laws of physics and that can act (run) asynchronously and respond to "events" (interactions with other particles).

If making every sand particle a separate object is too fine-grained, then divide the world into small blocks of let's say 1000 particles and simlute the behavior of these blocks instead.